# Send an image when someone says something

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I'm trying to get the bot to send an image when someone says something specific, ive already done it, but how do I send the image , here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const reactionEmoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === '7c2gaheiowu31compressed');
const clientPY = '7xxx45076137459732'

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    const mentionedMembersCollection = message.mentions.members;
    if (message.content.includes('play') || message.content.includes('time')) {
        
        message.react(reactionEmoji);

        const reply = ['No', 'You know? you will get sick', 'You really should stop']
        const show = reply[Math.floor(Math.random() * reply.length)];

        message.send(show)
     }
    if (mentionedMembersCollection.has('4xxx56331777245185') || mentionedMembersCollection.has('70xxx2119722278943')) {
        if(message.author.id === clientPY){
            message.channel.send('hello')
        }
    }
});

bot.login('ODI1MTxxxxxxxx1NzI4.YF5FAg.3bim466DN7HT_Ixxxxxxxxxxx');
```

and btw don't get bothered by the last section its for a friend

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MessageAttachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment):

```js
const image = new MessageAttachment('./reply.png');
message.channel.send('hello', image);
```

You can use a URL instead of a local file if needed:

```js
new MessageAttachment('https://example.com/image.png');
```

Comment: tysm! you saved me